# Pandas Dataframe interpreting columns as float instead of String

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, types

I want to import a csv file into a pandas dataframe. There is a column with IDs, which consist of only numbers, but not every row has an ID.

```
   ID      xyz
0  12345     4.56
1           45.60
2  54231   987.00
```

I want to read this column as String, but even if I specifiy it with

`df=pd.read_csv(filename,dtype={'ID': str})`

I get

```
   ID         xyz
0  '12345.0'    4.56
1   NaN        45.60
2  '54231.0'  987.00
```

Is there an easy way get the ID as a string without decimal like `'12345'`without having to edit the Strings after importing the table?

Comment: Is possible empty values in numeric columns?

Comment: If your concern is output format, then fix this when you export the data (e.g. `to_csv`, `to_string`), *not* by changing your underlying data (which looks fine) to awkward types.

Comment: I think you can upgrade your pandas version and all working nice.

Comment: I mean my underlying data is a csv file with an ID that is not ment to be taken numeric but as the name suggest as an identification. String seems to be the best representation for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution could be this, but after you have imported the df:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(int).astype(str)
```

Or since there are `NaN` with:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else str(int(x)))
```

Comment: Doesn't work, because I have empty cells, and NaN values can't be converted to int

Comment: That worked thank you. Was trying smthng similar but yours works way better

Comment: This saved me after half an hour of looking through other answers that did not work. Thank you!

Comment: What shall we do in we have cell with  "00212" value? @joe

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution if missing values are not in numeric columns - ad parameter  `keep_default_na=False` for not convert empty values to strings, but it NOT convert to NaNs in all data, not always in first column, check also [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#na-values):

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""ID;xyz
0;12345;4.56
1;;45.60
2;54231;987.00"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep=";", dtype={'ID': str}, keep_default_na=False)
    print (df)
      ID     xyz
0  12345    4.56
1          45.60
2  54231  987.00
```

EDIT:

For me in pandas 0.23.4 working your solution perfectly, so it means bug in lower pandas versions:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""ID;xyz
0;12345;4.56
1;;45.60
2;54231;987.00"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep=";", dtype={'ID': str})
print (df)
      ID     xyz
0  12345    4.56
1    NaN   45.60
2  54231  987.00
```

Comment: It works for your example, but not my csv file. Only difference to previous result is that `NaN` became an empty string.
I am really confused, I checked my file again, but there are definetly no floats there.

Comment: @GeorgB - what is expected output in `ID` column instead empty string?

Comment: the empty columns don't matter, as long as I have an easy way to filter them out. I only need the non empty IDs as String without a ".0" at the end. The user Joe gave an answer that worked, so I can continue. Just have the feeling there is a way to do it while reading in the file and not afterwards.

Comment: @GeorgB - `df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else str(int(x)))` is your solution?

Comment: @GeorgB - What is your pandas version? Because in pandas `0.23.4` it working nice like you need.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because this doesn't address the *underlying problem*, which is *output format* [exporting data] rather than *input format* [which is fine].

Comment: Thanks for this solution!  Your EDIT: section with dtype={'ID': str} solved the issue for me! I was losing leading zeros that I wanted to keep, so I needed to read it with the correct schema.  Great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

#### Specify float format when writing to csv

Since your *underlying problem* is output format when exporting data, no manipulation is required. Just use:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', float_format='%.0f')
```

Since you want only specific columns to have this formatting you can use [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html):

```
def format_int(x):
    return f'{x:.0f}' if x==x else ''

with open('file.csv', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(df.to_string(formatters={'ID': format_int}))
```

#### Keep numeric data numeric

> There is a column with IDs, which consist of only numbers

If your column only includes numbers, **don't convert to strings!** Your desire to convert to strings seems an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Numeric identifiers should stay numeric.

#### Float `NaN` prompts upcasting

Your issue is `NaN` values can't coexist with integers in a **numeric** series. Since `NaN` is a `float`, Pandas forces upcasting. This is natural, because the `object` dtype alternative is inefficient and not recommended.

If viable, you can use a sentinel value, e.g. `-1` to indicate nulls:

```
df['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'], errors='coerce').fillna(-1).astype(int)

print(df)

      ID     xyz
0  12345    4.56
1     -1   45.60
2  54231  987.00
```

Comment: `If your column only includes numbers, don't convert to strings!` - it OP need convert numeric to strings, why not? What is wrong about it?

Comment: @jezrael, [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): "The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem."

Comment: OK, please add your commnet about XY problem to comment under question, but if need convert to strings numeric column it is absolutely not wrong.

Comment: I need them as strings, or at least integers that can be converted to strings.
I will try your method if I dont find another option, but I'll have to remove the -1 every time I save the file.

Comment: I donvote becasue `don't convert to strings!` is wrong statement.